# Rust : Best way to pass a generic function to a generic?

Tags: c++, rust

I'm an experienced C++ programmer and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do a thing in Rust. A common pattern you see in C++ is to pass a class as a template parameter, where the class has templated methods on it to perform some function. For example `std::map` takes the `Compare` template parameter, which is a templated functor used to compare keys. This is basically passing a templated function as a template argument. I use this a lot, typically applying operations to a data structure. For example below I’m applying operations to vectors by calling the static `call` method on the thing passed in as the first template param. I'll also sometimes have some `constexpr` members in the passed in classes to do compile time control of the code applying the operation.

My searches have sadly failed me, what would be the equivalent pattern in Rust?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// define a class with a generic method to add things
struct AddOp {
  template<class L, class R>
  static auto call(const L& l, const R& r)
  {
    return l + r;
  }
};

// define a class with a generic method to subtract things
struct SubOp {
  template<class L, class R>
  static auto call(const L& l, const R& r)
  {
    return l - r;
  }
};

// extend out to all range of binary operations, MulOp, DivOp etc....

// define a function that applies an operation to vectors
template<class OP, class L, class R>
auto applyToVectors(const std::vector<L> &vecL,
                    const std::vector<R> &vecR)
{
  using ReturnType = decltype(OP::call(std::declval<L>(), std::declval<R>()));
  std::vector<ReturnType> returnValue;

  size_t sz = std::min(vecL.size(), vecR.size());
  returnValue.reserve(sz);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    returnValue.push_back(OP::call(vecL[i], vecR[i]));
  }
  return returnValue;
}


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<int> vec1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::vector<double> vec2 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};

  // apply Add to two vectors
  auto added = applyToVectors<AddOp>(vec1, vec2);

  // apply Sub to two vectors
  auto subtracted = applyToVectors<SubOp>(vec1, vec2);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to translate the concept into Rust? I mean, naively? I think it should work.

Comment: Sounds to me like you just want something like `trait Op { fn call<L, R>(l: L, r: R)}`,
`struct AddOp; impl Op for AddOp{ /*...*/ }`
and `fn apply<OP: Op, L, R>(l: L, r: R)`.

Comment: @ChrisB This is less general than the C++ code (it cannot accept non-generic functions).

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e25682f302e7b4013121c012c9a46a4e.

Comment: Alternatively, more similar to @ChrisB suggestion: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b097ea7c8f507bff7843ebdb85c3babd. You cannot use closures with this one, but you doesn't need to carry an instance of `Op` around.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: that is definitely more powerful, good point! Seems like the trait version might also be good enough for this usecase though. With your version, we might aswell call the functions `add` and `sub` directly and get rid of the `AddOp` struct.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm basically diving in trying to port one of my C++ libraries over to Rust as an experiment and learning exercise. One issue that looks hard to get around is the lack of `decltype` in Rust, and I'm a prolific user of `constexpr`

Comment: Hit return too soon! Thanks for the replies, I'm basically diving in trying to port one of my C++ libraries over to Rust as a learning exercise. One issue that looks hard to get around is the lack of `decltype` in Rust, it makes generic programming in C++ so much simpler. Another thing I lean on in C++ is constexpr, so to extend the above example, in each op I'd have `template<class L, class R> constexpr bool typesAreSupported()` and have a constexpr switch on the apply function to check types and handle failures. To deal with that looks like an awful lot of boiler plate matches in Rust.

Comment: Polymorphism in Rust works very differently from C++, with the need to declare all trait bounds ahead of time. It does have major advantages, though, and you'll get used to it. `constexpr` (or the Rust equivalent `const`) support is indeed lacking in Rust (for example, currently no const trait functions). Basic support is there, but more advanced use-cases are still to be designed and implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we really need to explicitly describe the abstract layer further than the specification of the expected signature of the `FnMut` to be used.

In simple cases, as the simple addition and substraction in the example below, directly specifying the operation in a closure is quite concise.
When it comes to the combination of a few operations, as the conversion before the addition, the direct usage of a simple closure is still readable.

If the computation is more complicated, with an internal state for example, the closure still applies but could be found difficult to read.
In this case, we can simply delegate all the details to an external implementation (structure, function, whatever suits...) concisely invoked from the closure.
This last situation is quite similar to the `AddOp` and `SubOp` of your example, but is only necessary for complicated cases; this reduces boilerplate for trivial cases.

```rust
fn apply_to_slices<Left, Right, Res>(
    left: &[Left],
    right: &[Right],
    mut operation: impl FnMut(&Left, &Right) -> Res,
) -> Vec<Res> {
    std::iter::zip(left, right)
        .map(|(l, r)| operation(l, r))
        .collect()
}

struct Complicated {
    state: i32,
}
impl Complicated {
    fn compute(
        &mut self,
        left: &i32,
        right: &f32,
    ) -> String {
        self.state += 1;
        if self.state % 2 == 0 {
            format!("+ {}", *left as f32 + right)
        } else {
            format!("× {}", *left as f32 * right)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec1 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let arr2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
    let arr3 = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5];
    //
    let res = apply_to_slices(&vec1, &arr2, |l, r| l + r);
    println!("simple addition: {:?}", res);
    //
    let res = apply_to_slices(&vec1, &arr2, |l, r| l - r);
    println!("simple substraction: {:?}", res);
    //
    let res = apply_to_slices(&vec1, &arr3, |l, r| *l as f32 + r);
    println!("conversion and addition: {:?}", res);
    //
    let mut state = 0;
    let res = apply_to_slices(&vec1, &arr3, |l, r| {
        state += 1;
        if state % 2 == 0 {
            format!("+ {}", *l as f32 + r)
        } else {
            format!("× {}", *l as f32 * r)
        }
    });
    println!("complicated operation: {:?}", res);
    //
    let mut comp = Complicated { state: 0 };
    let res = apply_to_slices(&vec1, &arr3, |l, r| comp.compute(l, r));
    println!("delegated operation: {:?}", res);
}
/*
simple addition: [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
simple substraction: [-9, -18, -27, -36, -45]
conversion and addition: [2.1, 4.2, 6.3, 8.4, 10.5]
complicated operation: ["× 1.1", "+ 4.2", "× 9.9", "+ 8.4", "× 27.5"]
delegated operation: ["× 1.1", "+ 4.2", "× 9.9", "+ 8.4", "× 27.5"]
*/
```